# Parse JSON string inside activiti bpmn

Tags: json, alfresco, activiti, bpmn, jsonparser

Greetings to the community! I am using `Alfresco 6.0.0 Community edition` with the embedded `Activiti` engine. I am creating many kind of different processes/tasks through .bpmn files and now I would like to `somehow achieve the following scenario`:

1) Deploy a .bpmn file with 2 `usertasks` (**usertask1 -> seqflow -> usertask2**).

2) While being on the first task I set/update a process variable and set to it a JSON formatted String (f.e "`{ id: '100', name:'X'}`" )

My question is **if there is any possible way to parse that JSON (f.e to obtain the 'id' or the 'name' values ) inside the bpmn??** I want to achieve this inside the usertask2, is there any possible way? Maybe something in the `ScriptTaskListener` or any other listener??  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks :)

Here is the usertask

```
 <userTask id="task2" name="${nameSetOnTask1}"
        activiti:formKey="wf:adhocTask">
       <documentation> Second task </documentation>
       <extensionElements>
           <activiti:taskListener event="create" class="org.alfresco.repo.workflow.activiti.tasklistener.ScriptTaskListener">
              <activiti:field name="script">
                 <activiti:string>
                  var json = execution.getVariable('json') <!-- this is the string with json value -->

                 </activiti:string>
              </activiti:field>
           </activiti:taskListener>
       </extensionElements>
    </userTask>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**SOLVED**

I managed to parse the Json String using the Javascript's `JSON.parse` function

```
<activiti:string>
   var json = execution.getVariable('json')
   var jsonObject= JSON.parse(json) ;
   var idValue = jsonObject.id                        
</activiti:string>
```